# Why UIView calls getter method of frame on setting its frame?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, frame

`UIView` calls getter method of frame on setting its frame.

Below is tested code :

```
@interface Test: UIView

@end

@implementation Test

-(void) setFrame:(CGRect) frame {
    super.frame = frame;
    NSLog(@"Frame set!!!");
}

-(CGRect) frame {
    NSLog(@"Frame!!!");
    return super.frame;
}

@end

Test* inst = [[Test alloc] init];
inst.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 123, 123);
```

I found that it would call `frame` on `setFrame:`is called.
I'm eager to know what's going on there? Is there someone has any clue?

FYI, the output is:

```
Frame!!!
Frame set!!! // Due to the call of initWithFrame:
Frame!!!
Frame set!!! // Setter
```

Comment: Ask Apple.  They wrote the code.

Answer (score 0):

First thing below code,

```
Test* inst = [[Test alloc] init];
inst.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 123, 123);
```

should give output like,

```
Frame!!!
Frame set!!!
Frame!!!
Frame set!!!
```

I mean two times because first when you `alloc` and `init` it and second time when you setting frame.

Now come on main point,

It is not actually calling `frame` first, it is definitely calling `setFrame` first but in `setFrame` method,

```
   super.frame = frame;
```

calls `frame` method so that your output looks like!!

if you will comment `super.frame = frame;` in `setFrame` method then your `frame` method will not get called i think!

You should put `breakpoint` in both methods and then test!

**Update :**

Try below code,

```
 -(void) setFrame:(CGRect) frame {

super.frame = frame;
NSLog(@"Frame set!!!");
}

-(CGRect) frame1 {

NSLog(@"Frame!!!");
return super.frame;
}
```

or

```
-(void) setFrame:(CGRect) frame1 {

super.frame = frame1;
NSLog(@"Frame set!!!");
}

-(CGRect) frame1 {

NSLog(@"Frame!!!");
return super.frame;
}
```

now it will not call `frame1` method. You have given method name as `frame` that means you are `overriding` super class's `frame method` so if you call `super.frame = frame;` then it will definitely call `frame` method (if `overridden` then it will get called).

Comment: Yes, they will output twice because of calling of ```initWithFrame:```. I've corrected it in the post.

Comment: put breakpoint in both method and check. then comment `super.frame = frame;` and then check!

Comment: The main point is what I'm still confused about!!!  I don't get why ```setFrame``` method of UIView have to call ```frame``` method. That is unsafe for people could override ```frame``` method to do some nasty things that influence the layout.  And personally I think that call of ```frame```method should not be involved in.

Comment: because your are overriding `frame` method of super class. change that method to `frame1` then it will not get called. I am updating my answer with code snippet to understand!

Comment:  Maybe there's some mistakes on my expressing. I decided to inherit from ```UIView``` and override ```frame```&```setFrame``` method JUST to DETECT these two methods' calling status. And I'm exploring why ```UIView```  calls ```UIView```'s ```frame``` on UIView's ```setFrame```. That's what really makes me confused.

Comment: Changing ```frame``` to ```frame1```. How can I know whether ```UIView->frame``` is called then?

Comment: if you override it then it is getting calling this is the proof that `UIView->frame` is getting called!